# Installing Docker + tensorflow on Windows 10

Tags: windows, docker, tensorflow

I tried to install tensorflow and docker as followed link https://www.tensorflow.org/install/docker

I downloaded tensorflow image from the tensowflow Hub into the docker and then I tried to test tensorflow python script. 
Then I got error message below.
I think it's related with GPU but I just downloaded tensorflow/tensorflow:last and I don't need GPU version. 
I thought if I used docker + tensorflow I wouldn't get any error.
Is there anybody who can tell me what's wrong with this..

```
2020-02-15 08:24:32.759681: W tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:55] Could not load dynamic library 'libnvinfer.so.6'; dlerror: libnvinfer.so.6: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
2020-02-15 08:24:32.759786: W tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:55] Could not load dynamic library 'libnvinfer_plugin.so.6'; dlerror: libnvinfer_plugin.so.6: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
2020-02-15 08:24:32.759798: W tensorflow/compiler/tf2tensorrt/utils/py_utils.cc:30] Cannot dlopen some TensorRT libraries. If you would like to use Nvidia GPU with TensorRT, please make sure the missing libraries mentioned above are installed properly.
```

Comment: `I downloaded tensorflow image from the tensowflow Hub` I guess this is different. you need to install docker on your machine first and then you need to get the tensor flow image on it. The URL that you have given shows how to get tensor on your docker machine. The download tensorflow image is not containerized apparently.

Answer (score 5):

As https://www.tensorflow.org/install/docker says, "nvidia-container-runtime is only available for Linux". As for now, there's no way to provide GPU to docker containers if you're using Windows as a host system.

Comment: Still no support for Windows + Docker + Tensorflow GPU :(